# Is there a way to set the id value of new Django objects to start at a certain value?

Tags: django

Is there a way to set the counter of id values for objects in Django?

For example I have an set of objects 'Video' that are currently at id=100  the next time I create an object of type 'Video' it will be id=101. However I'd like to have all newly created Video objects start at id=2000. is there a way to do this?

Comment: An ugly hack would be to make a fixture that makes a dummy row in your database with ID=1999. The next auto-generated ID would be 2000 then.

Comment: really? so the auto_increment just begins from the max in the db? ie. not trying to fill in any holes? I didn't realize that. that's actually fine for what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a fixture that creates a dummy row in your database with ID=1999. The next auto-generated ID would be 2000 then.

This solution probably depends on you database backend to 'resume where you left off'. At least MySql and PostgreSQL do this (I guess every backend does this).

There's also a solution for MySql only (as far as I know) that consists of a SQL statement `ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;`

That wouldn't be database agnostic anymore, though.

Answer (score 28):

You can specify the ID when you create the object, as long as you do it before you save:

```
new = Video()
new.id = 2000
new.save()
```

You could just calculate the ID you wanted each time - though I'm not sure what's wrong with Django's auto ID fields ;)

Comment: I think the OP meant to ask if there is a way of configuring in Django the starting value for the sequence for auto-id's.