# How can my Model primary key start with a specific number?

Tags: python, django

I have a User model, I want its id start from `10000`, then its id should auto-increment like:

`10001`, `10002`, `10003`, `10004`...

My User class:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...
```

Is it possible to make it come true?

**EDIT-1**

Before ask this question, I have read this link:[Is there a way to set the id value of new Django objects to start at a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432217/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-id-value-of-new-django-objects-to-start-at-a-certain-v)

But I don't think the answers are good, so I mean if in Django there is a configuration for achieve this?

Comment: this would be much easier to do on the database side, maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318279/django-1-7-migration-to-add-raw-query-to-set-auto-increment-initial-value

Answer (score 29, accepted):

the way is the same as to do datamigrations with RAW_SQL, change APPNAME on your:

```
python manage.py makemigrations APPNAME --empty
```

inside the created file:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL(
        'ALTER SEQUENCE APPNAME_USER_id_seq RESTART WITH 10000;'
    )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to do it manually:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from django.contrib.auth.models import User

In [2]: u = User.objects.create_user('name', '', '')

In [3]: User.objects.filter(id=u.id).update(id=10000-1)
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: u.delete()
Out[4]:
(0,
 {'admin.LogEntry': 0,
  'auth.User_groups': 0,
  'auth.User_user_permissions': 0,
  'auth.User': 0})

In [5]: uu = User.objects.create_user('user', '', '')

In [6]: uu.id
Out[6]: 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set autoincrement field like:

```
user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

After this, you can run this command on the database side. You can run this python command by using signals:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE user_id RESTART WITH 10000;
```

You can do this by different method.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_syncdb
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor = cursor.execute(""" ALTER SEQUENCE user_id RESTART WITH 10000; """)
transaction.commit_unless_managed()

post_syncdb.connect(auto_increment_start, sender=app_models)
```

In Django, a model can't have more than one AutoField. And this is used to set a primary key different from the default key.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL add this in your migration file:
Replace TABLE_NAME and START_VALUE with your table's name and value with which you want to start.

```
operations = [        
        migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME AUTO_INCREMENT=START_VALUE ;')
]
```