# Django starting id with a specific number?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

i want to start using a app with a specific id and when i migrate i have a error that is saying that i `dont have permission or does not exist`. Well i am already `db_owner` so maybe the error is when i do `ALTER SEQUENCE`on my migrations.

**My Project**

```html
myproject/
     |-- myproject
     |-- dpo/
         |-- projeto/
            |-- models.py
```

**Projeto model.py**

```html
class Projeto(models.Model):
  ..........
```

So i do `python manage.py makemigrations dpo --empty`
and then i went to file and in `opererations` i add : `migrations.RunSQL('ALTER SEQUENCE dpo_projeto_Projeto_id RESTART WITH 7000;')` and i have this error `Cannot alter the sequence 'dpo_projeto_Projeto_id', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Comment: well is not duplicate , because i try that and it is not working

Comment: Then login your database console and run SQL statement on your model

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number/50757476#50757476

Comment: already try that , and weh i am creating a new projeto i have this error `'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_projeto'`

Comment: How you try to create

Comment: i am trying do this `u = Projeto.objects.create_projeto()`

Comment: it should be `u = Projeto.objects.create()`

Comment: but i have fields that cannot be null so i cant do that

Comment: so i create a object (not in console) and try to do `Projeto.objects.filter(id=1).update(id=1000)` but still not luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number/50757476#50757476)

If this won't work then follow these step

```
>>> u = Projeto.objects.create()
>>> Projeto.objects.filter(pk=u.pk).update(id=10000)
```

In `create` method you may require to pass model mandatory fields with value like this

```
Projeto.objects.create(name='Test Project')
```

Comment: i only need to put the `name='Test Project'` or i need to do that to all my mandatory fields ?

Comment: as I have many required fields I created directly in the database and I did  `u = Projeto.objects.filter(id=1)` but when i do the `Projeto.objects.filter(pk=u.pk).update(id=10000)` it is giving error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'` so i did `Projeto.objects.filter(pk=u[0].pk).update(id=10000)` and i have another error `]Cannot update identity column 'id'.`

Comment: i already emty the database, only have 1 id , and the value is `1`

Comment: Change the value from where you want to start your primary key value

Comment: and how do i change?

Comment: Projeto.objects.filter(pk=1).update(id=10000) then see what is the id of the objects in database

Comment: Ah SQL Server not permitted you.. All are the step already taken are write. But now I suggest you manually enter into database then change the value by SQL Server

Comment: i think i will drop and create datebase on sql server and on query i will do something like `[id] [int] IDENTITY(7000,1) NOT NULL,`. the only problem is that when i drop table, i need to delete my `FOREIGN KEY constraint` and make it again

Comment: Apology! I does not work with SQL Server, that why I can't help you about this. I test it on sqlite3, PostgreSQL and it's working fine.

Comment: I did as I said I would and it's working thanks for everything