# Add a prefix to primary key in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to add a Prefix(YNT) to the primary key in django model

Models.py

```
class testmodel(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(max_length=500, primary_key=True)
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, null=True)
```

How Can I do That ? also instead of starting the primary key from 1 can I start it from 1000 ?

I want the table to look like this

```
product_id    product_short_code

YNT1000        PP001
YNT1001        PL023
```

Comment: `YNT1000` is a string, you can't add that in a `IntegerField`. You need `CharField` for that. You can make `CharField` as a primary key but there may be performance issues as varchar lookup is slower than integer. Integer takes less space than varchar. Instead of this you can create a new column to store `product_id`

Comment: from designing view point you shouldn't use string as primary key, you should set product_id as a custom field instead of setting it as primary key

Comment: use property field if you want fetch in djagno and format integer to your requirements.but this wont store in database only accessable in django

Comment: @NalinDobhal I agree it;s slower but still how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, It is not a good idea using string as a primary key. You can use helper method like on the following.

```
class testmodel(models.Model):
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, null=True)

    def product_id(self):
       return f'YNT{self.id}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change IntegerField to CharField in testmodel class.

```
class testmodel(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, primary_key=True)
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, null=True)
```

If you want that your primary key start any given specific number. Please follow above link. 
[How can my Model primary key start with a specific number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number)

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches that you should follow to achieve this:

**1.** If Prefix is common for all the entries then you can create a field in your model and add the prefix while getting the value.

```py
class testmodel(models.Model):
    product_code = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, null=True)

    @property
    def product_id(self):
        return f"YNT{self.product_code}"
```

**2.** If Prefix is not common for all the entries then you can create a field in your model to store the prefix and add the prefix while getting the value.

```py
class testmodel(models.Model):
    product_code = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    product_prefix = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='YNT')
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, null=True)

    @property
    def product_id(self):
        return f"{self.product_prefix}{self.product_code}"
```

**3.** If you want to create `CharField` as `primary_key` then you

```py
def create_id():
    // code for creating unique ids. assuming the id will be stored in _id variable.
    return f"YNT{_id}"

class testmodel(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, default=create_id)
    product_short_code = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0, null=True)
```

With the 3rd approach you have to make sure the primary key is always unique.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should see the primary key as a internal Django mechanism to reference and link objects.

Then if you want another, human readable id you can always create a char field `product_id` that would be as simple as `'YNT' + str(1000+id)` which you can save using the [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#post-c) signal. You can also add an index to said field to make querying faster if needed.

Example:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def set_product_id(instance, created, **_kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.product_id = 'YNT' + str(1000 + instance.id)
```

But still, your relations should be on the default pk and not on the id.