# How to change the beginning id in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to set an AutoField starting point to 1000, instead of 1, 2, 3, ... I want to make it 1001, 1002, 1003, ... here's the model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(min_length=4)
```

getting this error after running `makemigrations` command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\mhlogo\users\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class User(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\mhlogo\users\models.py", line 6, in User
    id = models.AutoField(min_length=4)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2357, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_length'
```

using django 3.1 and mariadb 10.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can my Model primary key start with a specific number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number)

Comment: got this error `"Table 'mhlogo.users_member_id_seq' doesn't exist")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it to work with an extra SQL command on an empty migration which is generated by:

```
python manage.py makemigrations users --empty
```

and added this SQL command to it:

```
migrations.RunSQL(
            'ALTER TABLE users_member AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;'
)
```

and at the end `python manage.py migrate`