# Set Django auto-increment primary key to specific value

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have an Order model for which I grabbed a bunch of orders from an older system.
As we wanted to preserve the ID, I set it manually during the migration.

However, this has thrown of the auto-increment key.  It's no longer correct.

How can I set the auto-increment to start from a specific value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can my Model primary key start with a specific number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number)

Comment: Indeed that's the gist. Thank you