# Django is not using proper id autoincrement number after migrating to Postgres DB

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I migrated my Django database from Sqlite into Postgres, the data is properly set and tested when reading.

The thing is that, when I try to add a new registry into the table, Django is using id number as 1 instead to be the last registry id plus one.

That of course returns an error, something like this:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/accounting/expense/add/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounting_expense_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

How can I make Django to use the proper id number when trying to save a registry?

I'm aware there is a way to set Django to begin the count on a specific number, but I wanted to know if there is a way to tell Django to look at the database (which is populated) and use that id count.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can my Model primary key start with a specific number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number)

Comment: Not exactly, I mean, I can do that definitely and it will work. But I wanted to know if there was a way for Django to know the last id so it will start from there. Because the db is populated and it was working properly in sqlite, but after the migration to postgres it started like if it was empty.