# Alter primart key in django model, must start with 1001

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a project, in which we have requirement that we have to start our primary key by 1001. The framework used is Django here.
So, we have to create a migration having id as alter field. But I don't know how to alter sequence of primary key. From some articles, I use auto_increment but it gives error of undefined.

Thanks

Comment: you can follow this solution though I'm not sure it will fullfill your requirements or not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757235/how-can-my-model-primary-key-start-with-a-specific-number

Answer (score 0):

For postgres

```
alter sequence model_id_seq restart with 1000;
```

For sqlite

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET SEQ=1000 WHERE NAME='Table_name';
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing you could do is in you migrations file create a RunPython script, and in there create 1000 records of whatever you need to start at pk 1001, and after that you delete all of these objects. Then the next object you will create for that model will have pk 1001. Not really pretty, but it would work.